# Texas Hold'em Rules

Tags: texas-hold-em, rules

This is my favorite poker game. I never found a list of all the rules of playing.
For example I play with my friends every weekend and in some cases we argue, if we where supposed to split or one to take it all.

One of those situation is the following:
on the table there are   3, 4, 5, A, 6 : flush
and the two players that remained on this game have both 2, 7 and 3, 7.
Who wins ? I knew that if the highest cards where all on table, then split,other wise the guy with the second best card, higher than 10 wins, is this correct?

Please post other rules here, if you have them

Edit 1:
Best link so far that I use is [here](http://www.texasholdem-poker.com/handrank).

Edit 2:

None of the player has suit or color with the community cards.

Comment: What were the suits of the cards?  It matters in particular because each player had a hole card that might play, and they can't both be of the same suit.

Comment: This question is way too vague.

Comment: I don't think this type of question is useful in the initial beta period to attract experts to the site.

Comment: This could work as a community wiki, but it needs more research.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the best 5 cards (each player + community) to make the decision. If the best 5 cards are equal among all players (as in your case), you split.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your specific example, if there's a flush on the table (say 3, 4, 5, 6, A spades), and the two players have no over spade (a spade higher than the 6 on the table), and there is no straight flush (no one has the 2 of spades), then they split the pot.

If they both have 7s, per your example, they are meaningless if they aren't spades.  If one has a 7 of spades, though, then they have the *higher* flush (A/7 high, vs. A/6 high), and win the whole pot.

If the 2 is a spade, then that player wins because it would give that player a straight flush, which is a higher hand than a flush.  However, if, in a slightly different example, the table were 3,4,5,T,A of spades, then the player with the 2 of spades would split it (assuming that was the only other spade), as it would be discarded for the higher, shared 3,4,5,T,A flush.

Comment: This isn't quite correct. The 2 of spades makes a straight flush in this example and will be better than any other spade (except the 7, because it would be the better straight flush).

Comment: @RoToRa Doh!  Missed that straight flush possibility.  Thanks for catching it.  I've edited to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

The standard rule book most often used for poker games is [Robert's Rules of Poker](http://www.lasvegasvegas.com/poker/rules.php).  He also has a version tailored to [home games](http://pokercoach.us/RobsPkrRulesHome.htm).

In the specific case of a flush on the board, unless someone has a card in their hand that can make a straight flush, or a card of the flush suit that is higher than the lowest card on the board, the pot will be split by everyone who is still in the hand at showdown.

There are always only 5 cards used per hand.  If the best hand that can be made uses the 5 cards on the board, hole cards don't matter.